# How do get customisation of arrows to work in Slick Slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I just can't seem to get my very own customisation arrows to work with slick slider JS. With the code below I have manage to get rid of the default buttons, but my arrows do not show. Could anybody help please. Thank you.

HTML:

```
<section id="testimonial"> <!-- Testimonial section -->
    <div class="slider"> 
      <div><img src="img/testimonial-1.png" alt="Testimonial from Bartholomew Watson of Abicord Consulting"></div>  
      <div><img src="img/testimonial-2.png" alt="Testimonial from Dwayne Ferguson of CC Collect"></div>
      <div><img src="img/testimonial-3.png" alt="Testimonial from David Jamilly of Kindness UK"></div>
      <div><img src="img/testimonial-4.png" alt="Testimonial from Sergey Slepov of Credit Suisse"></div>
    </div>
   </section>
```

CSS:

```
.slick-next::before {
        background: url('../img/right-arrow.png') no-repeat;
        content: "";
        display: block;
        height: 15px;
        width: 15px;
}
.slick-prev {
        background: url('../img/left-arrow.png') no-repeat;
        content: "";
        display: block;
        height: 15px;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('.slider').slick({
        slidesToShow: 1, 
        slidesToScroll: 1, 
        autoplay: true, 
        autoplaySpeed: 2000,
        arrows: true,
        prevArrow: '<div class="slick-prev"></div>',
        nextArrow: '<div class="slick-next"></div>'
      });

});
```

Comment: Please do not edit your question to include a new problem. Instead, create a new question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess your images are bigger than 15px, and that's why you don't see them. If that's the case, do this:

```
background-size: contain;
```

And why do you use the pseudo element

> .slick-next::before

for the next button? That's unnecessary. The same goes for "content" property on the slick-prev button.

Just do this:

```
.slick-prev, .slick-next {
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

    /* to position the arrows left and right at the bottom of slider */
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    bottom: 0;
}

.slick-prev {
    background-image: url('../img/left-arrow.png');

    /* place button left */
    left: 0;
}
.slick-next {
    background-image: url('../img/right-arrow.png');

    /* place button right */
    right: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Did you try to give the arrows a higher z-index? See: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/z-index/

Comment: Thank you so much appreciated. How would I position the arrows in the middle but keeping the arrows on the left and right?

Comment: bottom: calc(50% - half the height of the arrow), so it would be like this in your case: bottom: calc(50% - 7.5px);

Comment: Thats great! If I wanted to move the arrows in a bit, with the left arrow moving slightly into the right and right arrow moving slightly into the left. Is that possible?

Comment: For that you can adjust the "left" and "right" properties, which are set to 0 in the code above. Just change that to whatever you want like "left: 10px" or so.

Comment: @FrankDerbin Hi mate, hope you keeping well? I need your help and advice with progress bar. How do I add loading automated percentage? Look at my code above. Thank you

Comment: Replace your animation function with this: $('.progress-bar').stop().animate({left: progressTotal}, {progress: function(a, p, c ) {$('.some-counter-element-where-to-display-progress').html(Math.round( 100 * p ) + "%");},duration:animationLength}); For more information check the docs: http://api.jquery.com/animate/ There's the progress function I am using.

Comment: And just on a side note: There's a progress html element, which is exactly  for that, showing progress of something: https://css-tricks.com/html5-progress-element/

Comment: Hi @FrankDerbin I managed to get the automated percentage to work with the progress bar. My progress bars are in two columns, three rows in each. The sub headings are position the left of the progress bar. How do I get the percentage number to position on the left of the progress bar? Look at the edited code above please. Thank you.